# SItecore Field renderer not working in page editor

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore7, asp.net-webpages

Field renderer was working fine on mvc but now we moved to web pages, and i am converting my layouts & renderings to webpages but field renderer are not working in page editor mode but in published mode looking fine. page editor screen shot is attached.

Field rendered as

```cs
<sc:Text ID="Title" Item="<%# ((Sitecore.Data.Items.Item)Container.DataItem) %>" Field="Navigation Title" runat="server" />
```

and

```cs
<%# FieldRenderer.Render(Container.DataItem as Sitecore.Data.Items.Item, "Navigation Title") %>
```

tryied both but same result :) any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: does the FieldRenderer work if you use it outside the repeater?

Comment: Dear, @EhabElGindy same for fieldrendere outside & inside of repeater.
I have navigation in repeater and copyright & logo outside of the repeater but same result.

Comment: I wonder if something else on the page breaking the page editor. Can you create a new layout that contains only a FieldRenderer and use it for testing?

Comment: Yeah, @EhabElGindy Field renderers on default sub-layout ("Sample Datasource Sublayout.ascx") are working fine. means I would have to trace out my own sublayout.

Comment: do you need any more help with this question?

Comment: @EhabElGindy Thanks for your value able responses, problem was form inside body tag. which was missing, :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have av vague memory of seeing this error before. If I remember right, the problem was that Sitecore couldn't do all its Page Editor magic properly by inserting scripts etc into the html header and body. It's worth I try to just verify that your layout forms a proper html document and having the head and a form accessible from the server, such as this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
</head>
<body>
<form runat="server">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I was a long time ago I used webforms with Sitecore, so I don't remember exactly what components Sitecore hooks into in order to make the editor works, but having a page structure as above should be good to go.

Hope it helps

// Mikael

Comment: mikaelnet thanks for your reply,
      Problem is resolved by the hint of @Ehab EIGindy that something is missingg from HTML DOM & it was form tag inside body.
I am back to webforms after a long time and copied the markup from MVC Layout so missed it.
Again thanks alot dear.